# Doxygen Custom Tags

Tags: testing, doxygen

I want to create a custom tag which contains the ticket number and also the link to the Doors tool in doxygen

```
#  @sw_requirement{TESTID, https://xyz}
```

for one argument tried the following way :

```
ALIASES +="requirement{1}=@xrefitem requirement \"Requirements\" \"Requirements Traceability\" <a href=\"https://yxx.com/tracker08/browse/\1\">\1</a>"
```

which works fine.

Doxygen version 1.9.2

I tried the following way :

```
ALIASES += sw_requirement{2}=@xrefitem sw_requirement \"Requirement(s) under Test\" \"requirement based tests\"
```

this doesnt generate the required output

Comment: Which version of doxygen? I assume you want a custom command with 2 arguments, this can be accomplished by means of an `ALIASES` setting, see https://www.doxygen.org/manual/config.html#cfg_aliases and https://www.doxygen.org/manual/custcmd.html . Where do you have problems?

Comment: Hi I used alias something but I am not getting the output as I want. For one input it works fine for me "requirement{1}=@xrefitem requirement \"Requirements\" \"Requirements Traceability\" <a href=\"https://jira.com/tracker08/browse/\1\">\1</a>"  but when I add one more value it doesn't come as desired  . I am using the latest version of doxygen.                        "sw_requirement{2}=@xrefitem sw_requirement \"Requirement(s) under Test\" \"requirement based tests\"

Comment: I tried something like this : "sw_requirement{2}=@xrefitem sw_requirement \"Requirement(s) under Test\" \"requirement based tests\"

Comment: Please add your additional information (including doxygen version) into the question. I don't see anywhere the arguments you want to use i.e the `\1` and `\2` in the second `ALIASES`

Comment: I don't know where you want the flexibility so hard to tell, but you managed for 1 argument, so 2 arguments is just a small enhancement to it. Please give a small example (in the question).

Comment: In your first example there is the "placeholder `\1` but in your second example I don't seen `\1` nor `\2`

Answer (score 0):

```
"sw_requirement{2}=@xrefitem sw_requirement \"Requirement(s) under Test\" \"requirement based tests\" \1\2"
```

Fixed my issue